# request.raw_post trying to pull data from it

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
  def search_results
       @keyword = request.raw_post
       @tutors = Tutors.find(:all,:conditions => ["first_name LIKE ?", '%' + "raul" + '%'])    
  end
```

I am trying to get some information out of `request.raw_post`, but it is giving me this long string: "authenticity_token=HxxkPMpSr0kHZOVZIYbpMti217BTeUa5G2vX8zbs8ig%3D&keyword=alex&authenticity_token=HxxkPMpSr0kHZOVZIYbpMti217BTeUa5G2vX8zbs8ig%3D."

Basically, I just to get "alex," where it says "keyword=alex." How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that value, I would suggest using `params[:keyword]`.

Or alternatively, `request.raw_post.split(/&/).grep(/keyword=/).first.split(/=/).last`

Comment: yea, that is exactly what I did.