# Confirm SNS subscription on HTTP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I created an Amazon SNS Topic and added 2 subscriptions.

1. My email id which works fine after confirmation.
2. HTTP URL of an amazon ec2 instance.

The problem now is I cannot understand how to confirm the subscription for the HTTP URL.
I cannot see the post request on the apache access.log.
Do I have to look somewhere else for the message.

I already have a rails project deployed via passenger on the server.
Should I check for the post request via Rails code?

Answer (score 12):

Same issue, in fact it is RAW POST, you can read it with :

```
$post = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

put it in your destination url, and if you want for example send it on your e-mail to see it.

After that you can confirm : http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/sns/latest/api/API_ConfirmSubscription.html

Source : https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=364666#364666

EDIT : actually this is in JSON and there is an variable "SubscribeURL", copy paste in navigator and it validate the subscription !

Edit 2 : Sorry for php, it seems in rails it is on :

```
request.raw_post
```

[request.raw_post trying to pull data from it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366979/request-raw-post-trying-to-pull-data-from-it)

Comment: Assmuming it is php, sorry I can't help on rails, look for RAW POST DATA !

Comment: I reached here searching for a PHP solution so your answer is still very relevant to searches

Comment: Thanks, it's working on my end. Thanks for saving my time.